# authenticating bank account log in with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to build an application for a project that'll log into my bank account and compute a bunch of stuff. I'm using the scrapy to be able to do this but I can't get through the logging in part.

The weird thing about this is that first you need to input your username, submit and then you'll get redirected to a page where you put your password, submit and finally get to your account.

This is what I'm doing:

```
 import scrapy                                                                                                                                               
 2                                                                                                                                                            
 3class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):                                                                                                                           
 4    name = 'www.firstmerit.com'                                                                                                                             
 5    start_urls = ['https://www.firstmeritib.com/Default.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fAccountHistory.aspx%3fa%3d1']                                                     
 6                                                                                                                                                            
 7                                                                                                                                                            
 8    def parse(self, response):                                                                                                                              
 9        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(                                                                                                            
10            response,                                                                                                                                       
11            formdata={'ctl00$txtUsername': 'valid username'},                                                                                                                 
12                                                                                                              
13            callback = self.after_login                                                                                                                     
14        )                                                                                                                                                   
15                                                                                                                                                            
16    def after_login(self, response):                                                                                                                        
17        # check login succeed before going on                                                                                                               
18        if "User Name:" in response.body:                                                                                                                   
19            self.logger.error("Login failed")                                                                                                               
20            return                                                                                                                                          
21        else:                                                                                                                                               
22            print("you got through!")                                                                                                                       
23            print()
```

The URL in question is up there if you want to check stuff out, but I'm dealing with this buried a bit under the 
[form in the HTML.][1
So far I haven't gotten through... That username is a dummmy one but the correct and real one should get you to the page that asks you for a password, and yet it doesn't.

(also the code just shows the username logging part, not the password, I guess I'll worry about that later)

Thank you!

EDIT: Upon further inspection I realize that the log in button is wrapped in this:

```
<div id="divLogin" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnLogin')">
```

Does this mean it loads the next page through Javascript and so I'll need to use other stuff like Selenium to get what I need?

Comment: For stuff that requires javascript to follow you will be best to use selenium for your scraping needs. While it is slow, much slower than non-browser scrapers, it will sure render it right (and there are some non-browser js powered engines out there, but compatibility on them varies wildly).

Comment: Thanks a lot! ^ I'll guess I'll get into that